Vertical padding in table cells containing matrices
I am trying to construct a table containing matrices.  There are solutions that use \booktabs, \arraystretch, and \extrarowheight, but I still can't find what I need.  Here is my MWE using booktabs which produces unwanted gaps in the table lines and not enough vertical space between the table header and first matrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bbold}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | p{1in} | p{1in} |} 
\toprule
matrix & condition 1 & condition 2
\\[2em]
\midrule
$\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & -e^{-i\theta} \end{bmatrix}$ & yes & no
\\[2em]
$\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta} & e^{i\phi} \\ e^{-i\phi} & e^{-i\theta} \end{bmatrix}$ & yes & yes
\\[2em]
$\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$ & no & no
\\[2em]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 

\end{document}


Another attempt using arraystretch gives too much vertical space between matrix rows and no vertical space between cells:
\begin{center}
\def\arraystretch{2}%
\begin{tabular}{| c | p{1in} | p{1in} |} 
\hline
matrix & condition 1 & condition 2
\\
\hline
$\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & -e^{-i\theta} \end{bmatrix}$ & yes & no
\\
$\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta} & e^{i\phi} \\ e^{-i\phi} & e^{-i\theta} \end{bmatrix}$ & yes & yes
\\
$\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$ & no & no
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 


Another attempt using extrarowheight gives too much vertical space between matrix rows, not enough vertical space between cells, and not enough vertical space between table header and first matrix
{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | p{1in} | p{1in} |} 
\hline
matrix & condition 1 & condition 2
\\
\hline
$\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & -e^{-i\theta} \end{bmatrix}$ & yes & no
\\
$\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta} & e^{i\phi} \\ e^{-i\phi} & e^{-i\theta} \end{bmatrix}$ & yes & yes
\\
$\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$ & no & no
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}} 


How do I add extra padding to the table cells without affecting the matrix rows and table lines?  I'm not keen on manually inserting something like \\[-1ex] at the end of every matrix row.  There also seems to be problems when I try to pad the areas around a \hline.

If you're not too attached to vertical rules in tables (you shouldn't be, because they make for harder reading, not easier), do
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c w{c}{1in} w{c}{1in} @{}}
\toprule
matrix & condition 1 & condition 2
\\
\midrule
\addlinespace
$\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & -e^{-i\theta} \end{bmatrix}$ & yes & no
\\
\addlinespace
$\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta} & e^{i\phi} \\ e^{-i\phi} & e^{-i\theta} \end{bmatrix}$ & yes & yes
\\
\addlinespace
$\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$ & no & no
\\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


If you insist in wanting the vertical rules, setting \extrarowheight is not the solution and neither is \\[2em].
You can use a strut based on the height and depth of the matrix, with 3pt (or what you deem suitable) added to them.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{bmatrixintabular}{+b}
 {%
  \sbox0{$\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}$}%
  \vrule height \dimeval{\ht0+3pt} depth \dimeval{\dp0+3pt} width 0pt
  \usebox0
 }{}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | w{c}{1in} | w{c}{1in} |} 
\hline
matrix & condition 1 & condition 2
\\
\hline
$\begin{bmatrixintabular} e^{i\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & -e^{-i\theta} \end{bmatrixintabular}$ & yes & no
\\
$\begin{bmatrixintabular} e^{i\theta} & e^{i\phi} \\ e^{-i\phi} & e^{-i\theta} \end{bmatrixintabular}$ & yes & yes
\\
$\begin{bmatrixintabular} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrixintabular}$ & no & no
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 

\end{document}



Thanks, this is helpful.  I was wondering how to incorporate cells that allow linebreaks?  The p{1in} in the \begin{tabular}{...} line allows me to insert a longer table header, eg. condition 1 (is essential) in the second column

@MedullaOblongata Use p{1in} if you want paragraphs instead of w{c}{1in}
